# Conflicting functions or simple fix?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm sure this is not as hard as I am making it but I am really stuck.

I need (C) to return "Y" or "N" based on today's date being beyond the expiration date. I need (B) to return a date exactly 2 years from (A) or blank if (A) is blank.

My original formula worked for B but if A was blank it returned a 1901 date. I added an IF and suddenly my C formula wasn't working and returned all "Y".

The picture is what I WANT it to look like.

[image]

Comment: If column A and B are blank, then do you want column C blank, too? You don't have that scenario in your picture.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want column C blank if column A is blank. Here are the formulas you need:

Cell B3:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",DATE(YEAR(A3)+2,MONTH(A3),DAY(A3)))
```

Cell C3:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",IF($B$1>B3,"Y","N"))
```

Drag down the formulas, and that's it.

[image]

Comment: It's not changing the field to Y for the two I have entered.  That's the problem I was having with my original formulas as well. :-(

Comment: @MariaM Works fine for me as per the screenshot I provided. Did you try these exact values and successfully repeat? What values are NOT working? And make sure the B1 value in your formula is locked... ie, $B$1.